# A way to reduce run-time

Tags: matlab, image-processing, runtime

I have a 2048x2048 image and I want to re-set the pixels values according to certain condition. The problem is that it takes houres (if not days) for the code to end. Is there a way to shorten the run-time? 
This is the function:

```
function ProcImage = ProcessImage(X,length,width)
 for i=1:length
    for j=1:width
        if X(j,i)<=0.025*(max(max(X(:,:))))
            X(j,i)=0;
        else
            if X(j,i)>=0.95*(max(max(X(:,:))))
                X(j,i)=(max(max(X(:,:))));
            end
        end
    end
end
ProcImage=X(1:end,1:end);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[Vectorize it](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). You don't need to compute the maximum value of `X` on every iteration, since it will be the same throughout. Compute it once, store that value, then use it later. You can also do away with the loops by using [element-wise logical operations and matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). Here's a simplified version that should be *much* faster:

```
maxX = max(X(:));
X(X <= 0.025.*maxX) = 0;
X(X >= 0.95.*maxX) = maxX;
```

Comment: maxX = max(max(X)); is even a bit faster ;-)

Comment: @bidi: Not based on my timing: `X = rand([2048 2048]); max1 = @() max(X(:)); max2 = @() max(max(X)); timeit(max1, 1) timeit(max2, 1)`

Comment: @gnovice: for the size of [2048 2048] you are right, they are nearly the same. One time the first one is faster and the next time the second one. But if you scale it to bigger matrices, the difference is getting bigger ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your image is a gray scale image that its values are in the range 0 to 255 here is a possible solution:

```
m = max(X(:));
tbl = 0:255;
tbl(tbl<=0.025*m)=0;
tbl(tbl>=0.95*m)=m;
X = tbl(int16(X)+1);
```